# Solving recurrence relation $T(n) = \sqrt{(n * T(\sqrt{n}) + n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I found a solution to the recurrence relation that I would like to discuss with you please:

$$T(n) = \sqrt{(n * T(\sqrt{n}) + n)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

As I understood, a lot of recurrence relations could be solved by mapping them to the master equation and then check to which case it belongs, which is much faster than **unrolling** recurrence equations to find the solution for it:

$$T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}) + f(n)$$

Some equations though like the above \ref{1} can not be mapped directly to master method to solve it, so some transformations are necessary as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) =\sqrt{(n * T(\sqrt{n}) + n)}\\
\log{T(n)} = \frac{1}{2}\log{n\times\left(T(\sqrt{n}) + 1\right)} \tag{2}\label{2}\\
\log{T(n)} \approx \frac{1}{2}\log{n\times\left(T(\sqrt{n})\right)} \tag{3}\label{3}\\
\end{align}
$$

**First transformation**: we can do our first transformation as follows by letting $S(n)=\log{T(n)}$

$$
\begin{align}
S(n) = \frac{1}{2}\log\left({n\times\left(T(\sqrt{n})\right)}\right) \tag{4}\label{4}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\log{n} + \frac{1}{2}\log{\left(T(\sqrt{n})\right)}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\log{n} + \frac{1}{2}S(\sqrt{n})\tag{5}\label{5}\\
\end{align}
$$

**Second transformation**: Again, the input form of $\sqrt{n}$ could be further simplified by letting $R(n) = S(2^n)$, so we have:

$$
\begin{align}
S(n) = \frac{1}{2}\log{2^n} + \frac{1}{2}S(\sqrt{2^n}) \tag{6}\label{6}\\
= \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2}S(\sqrt{2^n})\\
= \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2}R(n/2) \tag{7}\label{7}\\
\end{align}
$$

**Problem 1**: This is just a discussion please, so no solution is needed. In equation \ref{6}, what we are doing here is to let $R(n)$ takes part of the domain of the original input defined as in $S(n)$, so that means as I understand it that we are not taking the whole input but a form/part of it, so how that would mean that our new form/transformation defined by $R(n)$ is a valid please since it does not cover all the domain of $S(n)$ but part of it?

**Problem 2**: For equation \ref{7} please, how $ \frac{1}{2}S(\sqrt{2^n})$ becomes $\frac{1}{2}R(n/2)$ as I guess it should be  $\frac{1}{2}R(\sqrt{n})$, what do you think please.

**Problem 3**: once we get the simplified form: $R(n)= (1/2) R(n / 2) + (1/2) n$, if we try to apply master method here, we see that $f(n) = (1/2)n$ and $c=1$. For $\log_b{a} = \log_2{1/2}=-1$. We can see that $c=1 \gt -1$, so we have **case 3** that $c \gt \log_b{a}$, so we have $O(n^c)  = O(n)$, but the question I got says it's $O(n^{\frac{2}{3}})$, what do you think please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

$$
\log_2{T(n)} \approx \frac{1}{2}\log_2n+\frac 12\log_2T(\sqrt{n})
$$

making $\mathcal{T}(\cdot)=\log_2T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with the recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)=\frac z2+\frac 12\mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)
$$

This recurrence has the solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)=\frac 2z\left(\frac{4^{\log_2 z-1}}{3}+c_0\right)
$$

now going backwards with $z=\log_2 n$ we get finally

$$
T(n) = c_12^{\frac{1}{3} 2^{1-n} \left(4^n-1\right)}
$$

EDIT

The required solution follows

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)=\frac z2+\frac 12\mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)
$$

or

$$
\mathcal{T}(2^{\log_2 z})=\frac z2+\frac 12\mathcal{T}\left(2^{\log_2{\frac z2}}\right)
$$

now calling $\mathbb{T}(\cdot)=\mathcal{T}\left(2^{\log_2{(\cdot)}}\right)$ and $u=\log_2 z$ we follow with

$$
\mathbb{T}(u)=2^{u-1}+\frac 12 \mathbb{T}(u-1)
$$

This linear recurrence has the solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(u)=c_0 2^{1-u}+\frac{1}{3} 2^{1-u} \left(4^u-1\right)
$$

now going backwards with $u=\log_2 z$ we get

$$
\mathcal{T}(z)=\frac 2z\left(\frac{4^{\log_2 z-1}}{3}+c_0\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. One question please, we have no $2^{(.)}$ inside, so how  you managed to get $z$ instead inside $\mathcal{T}(z)$? If we are to replace $n$ inside $T$ by $z$, then $z= log n$, so $2^z = n$ as I understand it. Then we will have based on how I understand $z$ the following: $\mathcal{T}(2^z) = 1/2(z) + 1/2(\mathcal{T}(2^{z/2}))$. Please correct me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: The relationship you found is really $\log_2(T(2^z))=\frac 12 z + \frac 12 \log_2(T(2^{\frac z2}))$. The transformation gives us the $\mathcal{T}$ recurrence

Comment: I applied master method and I got case 3 on$
\mathcal{T}(z)=\frac z2+\frac 12\mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)
$. What do you think please? Since $c>log_b(a)$ so we have $O(n)$ without going for $T(n)$ back again as I understand that $\mathcal{T}$ complexity is same as of $T(n)$, is that correct please? Otherwise, how you get the solution for the recurrence equation please? Then, can you add to your solution please how you went back to $T(n)$ after you substitute the value of $z$?

Comment: Included the solution required.

Comment: Any comment con problem 1 of the OP?

Comment: Thank you very clear. Last question please, should not we have $\mathbb{T}(2^u)=2^{u-1}+\frac 12 \mathbb{T}(2^{u-1})$ instead of $
\mathbb{T}(u)=2^{u-1}+\frac 12 \mathbb{T}(u-1)$ as I did substitutions based on values you wrote for $u=\log{z}$